# Run some Linux command in PHP trail together

Tags: php, linux, bash, command-line, ssh2-exec

I wrote some php code that connected to vps through ssh

I know `ssh2_exec` can do it, but if I want run many command like:

```
ssh2_exec($connection, 'cd /home/ubuntu/');
ssh2_exec($connection, 'mkdir folder');
ssh2_exec($connection, 'cd folder');
ssh2_exec($connection, 'touch test.txt');
.
.
.
```

It doesn't work and only do first command. how can I run some many command trail together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write multiple command on one line separated by `;` or `&&` So you can follow below code

```
ssh2_exec($connection, 'cd /home/ubuntu/; mkdir folder; cd folder; touch test.txt');
```

OR

```
ssh2_exec($connection, 'cd /home/ubuntu/ && mkdir folder && cd folder &&touch test.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call the function `ssh2_exec` you are creating a new shell and executing a single command.

If you want to run a series of commands within the same shell, you can try separating them with semicolons or newlines within the same string. For example:

```
$commands = <<<'EOD'
cd /home/ubuntu
mkdir folder
cd folder
touch test.txt
EOD;

ssh2_exec($connection, $commands);
```